# How to run VM's within Ubuntu Linux without Virtualbox or any other type 2 hypervisors?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, kvm-virtualization, privacy

I am planning to move from Windows 7 to Ubuntu as it is free and due to privacy reasons. Is there any way to run VMs from within Ubuntu without any additional software like Virtualbox or any other type 2 hypervisors? I tried VirtualBox and it sucks in my opinion eventhough it is free. I heard that I could do this by installing KVM? Does this come automatically with Linux desktop version or do I have to install it manually?

If Ubuntu can't do this any other Linux distros with this ability to run VM's without installing any additional software?

Comment: Do you really need type-2 hypervisors? I mean, why would you want to run VMs on hardware without VT support? Performance is really really bad. KVM only supports VT enabled hardware. Please see also this Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/a/245197/88802

Comment: But the question is about doing it without type 2 hypervisors.

Comment: @Jacek VirtualBox supports both VT (even with virtio) and non-VT, which makes it both type-1 and type-2. I read the question as if he needs a type-2 hypervisor, though. The OP has to clarify further.

Comment: @ gertvdijk - My laptop supports VT. It has latest i7 processor. I would like to know whether there is inbuilt functionality within Ubuntu to create and install VMs. I dont want to install another piece of software like VirtualBox.

Answer (score -1):

KVM will be a good option - of course you still have to install proper pieces of software, KVM binaries, some extra tools etc. It integrates with Linux kernel (as modules), which make it pretty much type 1 virtualization.

Comment: But the question is for a type-2 hypervisor.

Comment: Not really - it says _without_ type 2 hypervisors (or extra software - which actually is still needed anyway, but that's not really a big surprise)

Comment: @ Jacek Is KVM my only option for creating and Installing VMs in Ubuntu? Is it easy to have KVM installed  - like downloading a package and installing it or do I have to run terminal commands to install KVM?

Comment: Definitely not an only option - you can also try xen, I think. Or you can still go for type-2 - like VirtualBox or maybe something else yet - I don't know them all. I think you should also be able to install VmWare Workstation - but that's again type-2.

Comment: Is it easy? Well - installation as such is very simple - apt-get will get you proper dependencies for kvm. All the rest is more about the quest configuration. Have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM   If you want to go easy way - you can setup then your guest using virt-manager (probably the best option for now). Later when you get more familiar with it - virsh in the console can be quite helpful in managing the whole stuff (at least for me)